# Constructing the BRST operator for the superstring

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, supersymmetry, ghosts, brst

In page 133 of Polchinski's String Theory textbook (ref. [1]), it is stated that given a set of constraints $\{G_I\}$ satisfying the algebra
$$[G_I,G_J] = i {g^k}_{IJ}G_K \,, \tag{4.3.12}$$
the BRST charge takes the following form
$$Q = c^IG_I - \frac{i}{2} {g^K}_{IJ} c^I c^J b_K \,, \tag{4.3.14}$$
where ($c^I,b^J$) are ghosts satisfying $\{b_I,c^J\}= \delta^J_{ \ I}$.

I am trying to apply the above formulas and obtain the BRST charge for the superstring given in eq. (10.5.24) in Polchinski's vol. 2 book (ref. [2]). In particular, the term that I am having trouble in obtaining is the first term in the second line of eq. (10.5.24).

As an example, I will show how I get the third term in the first line of eq. (10.5.24) in [2] and then state where I am having problems. I start with the ${\cal N}=1$ super Virasoro algebra
\begin{align} 
[L_m, L_n] & = (m-n) L_{m+n} + \tfrac{c}{12}(m^3 - m) \delta_{m,-n} \,, \tag{1}\\
[L_m , G_r] & = (\tfrac{m}{2} - r) G_{m+r} \,, \tag{2} \\
\{G_r, G_s\} & = 2 L_{m+r} + \tfrac{c}{12} (4r^2 -1) \delta_{r,-s} \tag{3}\,.
\end{align}
Then, from eq. (1), I can read the structure constant
$${g^{L_p}}_{L_m L_n}= - i (m-n) \delta^p_{m+n}\,. $$
So that, the corresponding term with this structure constant appearing in eq. (4.3.14) is
\begin{align}
- \frac{i}{2} {g^{L_p}}_{L_m L_n} c_{-m} c_{-n} b_p & = \sum_{m,n} \frac{(-1)}{2} (m-n) c_{-m} c_{-n} b_{m+n} \\
& = - \sum_{m,n} \frac{1}{2} (n-m) b_{-m -n} c_m c_n\,, \tag{4}
\end{align}
where I used that $c^m = c_{-m}$. Note that eq. (4) corresponds to the third term in the first line of eq. (10.5.24) in [2] as desired.

Now, let me explain where I found a problem in my calculations. From eq. (2), we have the structure constant
$${g^{G_s}}_{L_m G_r} = -i (\tfrac{m}{2} -r) \delta^p_{m+r} \,, $$
which appears in (4.3.14) in the following terms
\begin{align}
-\frac{i}{2} {g^{G_s}}_{L_m G_r} c^m \gamma^r \beta_s - \frac{i}{2} {g^{G_s}}_{G_r L_m} \gamma^r c^m \beta_s \stackrel{?}{=} 0 \,, \tag{5}
\end{align}
where to get the above equality I used the antisymmetry of the structure constants ${g^{G_s}}_{L_m G_r} = - {g^{G_s}}_{G_r L_m}$ and that $\gamma^r$ and $c^m$ commute. Eq. (5) is clearly wrong because it doesn't reproduce the first term of the second line in (10.5.24) of ref. [2].

Question: What is the mistake I am making in obtaining zero in eq. (5)?

---

[1] J. Polchinski, *String theory. Vol. 1: An introduction to the bosonic string*, Cambridge University Press (1998).

[2] J. Polchinski, *String theory. Vol. 2: Superstring theory and beyond*, Cambridge University Press (1998).